# A strange line gap appearing between two div element while making the screen small

Tags: html, css

I've reset the padding and margin but no change. Please review the code and tell me what's the problem

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

.child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #8540de;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

[image: small screen view here]

[image: big screen view here]

Comment: could you please provide more details about your small screen and big screen. What is the size we need to consider if we have to replicate? in which resolution the behaviour is observed?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Try box-sizing: border-box; and 100% height on container, overflow: hidden; to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: @Rishal When I make the screen less than 1000px in chrome browser inspector

Comment: margin: -1px; use this instead of 0px

Comment: @Liap chrome and edge

Comment: @rishal wouldn't it effect other element?

Comment: @SazzadSiam it will impact in very subtle manner, if you need only for specific divs then try using margin top for the second div relative to first div.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this bug. There's no line gap using the code snippet you provided